# Firebase ClassMapper ignoring provided setters

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to map a Firebase realtime DB to a Java class on Android. The class I am mapping to looks like this:

```
public class Thing {
    private String mName;
    private String mDescription;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.mDescription = description;
    }
}
```

This is passed to Firebase's `.getValue()`:

```
dataSnapshot.getValue(Thing.class);
```

But this logs a `ClassMapper` warning and doesn't set the value:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for name found on class com.example.android.demo.Thing
>   W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for description found on class com.example.android.demo.Thing

Why is it ignoring the setters provided for those fields?

Comment: Thanks, Frank, for fixing my icky tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue shown here is a misleading log message. `ClassMapper` won't use a setter unless there is a matching getter:

```
public class Thing {
    private String mName;
    private String mDescription;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.mName;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.mDescription = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.mDescription;
    }
}
```